# Cannot add foreign key constraint on a simple code help please

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

i am trying something apparently simple, but i just keep having the same error "Cannot add foreign key constraint", can anyone help me? I am using workbench with sql

```
drop table if exists table2;
create table if not exists table2(
    id_kind int not null,
    id_bod int not null,
    id_doc int not null,

    primary key (id_kind, id_bod, id_doc)
)engine=InnoDB default charset=latin1;

drop table if exists table1;
create table if not exists table1(
    id_mov int not null,    
    id_kind int not null,
    id_prod int,
    id_bod int not null,
    id_doc int not null,

    primary key (id_mov),   
    key id_kind (id_kind),
    key id_bod (id_bod),
    key id_doc (id_doc),

    foreign key table1 (id_kind) references table2 (id_kind),
    foreign key table1 (id_bod) references table2 (id_bod),
    foreign key table1 (id_doc) references table2 (id_doc)
)engine=InnoDB default charset=latin1;
```

Comment: id_kind needs to be the primary key for table1, it isn't so you can't create the FK constraint

Comment: that should be `foreign key (id_kind) references table1(id_mov)`

Comment: @RichardHansell, That is the usual way of doing things but I'm pretty sure a foreign key can reference any column of the same type.

Comment: I keep getting the same error, despite i added `primary key (id_kind)` to the code :/

Comment: @Arth, yes, I was being over-simplistic, a foreign key constraint must reference a column (or columns) that form a unique constraint on the referenced table.  A primary key is just a subset of a unique constraint.

Comment: @RichardHansell Ah yes! And I was being over-general!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are trying to add the `foreign key` `constraint` to the wrong table.
Presumably `table2` contains the kinds that are referenced by `table1`.

You'll have to reorder your code, `id_kind` should probably be the `primary key` for `table2` and you need an index on `id_kind` in `table1`:

```
drop table if exists table2;
create table if not exists tabla2(
    id_kind int not null,
    primary key (id_kind)
)engine=InnoDB default charset=latin1;

drop table if exists table1;
create table if not exists table1(
    id_mov int not null,
    id_kind int not null,
    id_prod int,
    primary key (id_mov),
    key id_kind (id_kind),
    foreign key table1_ibfk_1 (id_kind) references table2 (id_kind)
)engine=InnoDB default charset=latin1;
```

**UPDATE**

It now looks like you want a composite foreign key, try this for your table1:

```
drop table if exists table1;
create table if not exists table1(
    id_mov int not null,    
    id_kind int not null,
    id_prod int,
    id_bod int not null,
    id_doc int not null,

    primary key (id_mov),   
    key id_kind_id_bod_id_doc (id_kind, id_bod, id_doc),
    foreign key table1_ibfk_1 (id_kind, id_boc, id_doc) 
      references table2 (id_kind, id_boc, id_doc),
)engine=InnoDB default charset=latin1;
```

I'm still not sure what each of these tables represent, or what you are trying to achieve.

You use the `KEY` (synonym for `INDEX`) line to set up an `INDEX` in your table that the `FOREIGN KEY` uses.

[`FOREIGN KEY` docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: No problem, what are your doubts?

Comment: * Why you have to add `key id_kind (id_kind)`? what does that do?
* When I try to put more than one foreign key, i get the same error :S I will update the code of my question

Comment: Ohh! I think i get it now, i was misunderstanding the diagram i had to represent, and i wasn't considering the diagram to create the tables, THANK YOU again :) :)